# build.gradle errors while running android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I installed android studio for the first time but got lots of error!
I searched on the web but could not find anything that solve my problem.
now the problem is shown below :

[Look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQCyp.png)

---

this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vahid.game"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: post your grade file here, don't think anyone can help with that little information

Comment: I hope you have internet access, android studio tries to download libraries if they are not present. In your case i can see that "junit" isnt present. If you are doing at a beginner level and you dont need testing, you can very well go on remove "test compile junit XXXX" from your dependecies in build.gradle (app)

Comment: sorry where can i find gradle files?

Comment: Navigate to your app directory there you can find build.gradle file